# Preventing N+1 queries in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, query-optimization, entity-relationship, select-n-plus-1

I've seen a few examples of passing an `:include` hash value when calling one of ActiveRecord's `find` methods in Rails. However, I haven't seen any examples of whether this is possible via relationship methods.  For example, let's say I have the following:

```
def User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_favorites
  has_many :favorites, :through => :user_favorites
end

def Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_favorites
  has_many :users, :through => :user_favorites
end

def UserFavorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :favorite
end
```

All the examples I see show code like this:

```
User.find(:all, :include => :favorite)
```

But I don't see any examples showing the use of relationships.  Would it instead be possible for me to do something like this?

```
User.favorites(:include => :user)
```

Comment: These days, use [bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use relations as Class methods. It is instance methods. You can call

```
@user.favorites
```

Check out this screencast about Eager Loading

http://railscasts.com/episodes/22-eager-loading

It will be

```
 User.find(:all, :include => :favorites)
```

or for Rails 3.x

```
 User.includes(:favorites)
```

Comment: That didn't answer the question of whether I can use a relationship method instead of the `find` method.

Comment: That's too bad, kind defeats some of the simplicity of Rails.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: No it is quite natural, you just need to feel it :)

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that it defeats the purpose of the relationship methods.  If I'm always going to be calling `Class.find` instead of `instance.relationship`, then there's no reason for there to be a relationship method in the first place other than to define the entity relationship structure.

Comment: What should `Class.relationship` return? All classes with all related relationships? Ehmm...?

Comment: No, I'm saying `instance.relationship(:include => ...)` should essnentially do the same as `Class.find(:all, :include => ...)`, except that it should be scoped to the instance.  The way it is now, I have to manually scope the query when calling `Class.find` if I also want to benefit from the use of the `:include` option.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but what should `Class.relationship` use `joins` or `includes`? I mean which SQL JOIN it should use?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `:include` to your model's associations to eager load the second-order associations when the object is loaded.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

Comment: it appears this is now deprecated