# Is there any way to avoid excess ActiveRecord calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following ActiveRecord call in a Rails controller ("filings#index"):

```
@filings = Filing.order("created_at DESC").limit(limit).offset(start).joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN companies ON companies.id=filings.company_id")
```

Each Filing belongs_to a Company.  I would like to be able to access:

```
@filings.first.company
```

Without having to make an additional SQL query as that was the entire purpose of completing an OUTER JOIN in the first place.  However when I call @filings.first.company it performs an additional query:

```
SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = 989 LIMIT 1
```

How can I avoid this second query from taking place?  Shouldn't the information already have been stored as a result of the initial query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452340/preventing-n1-queries-in-rails

Comment: Im sure this has been asked and answered here many times before.  Look around for Preloading associations and includes.  Filing.includes(:company) would include the company association in the results.

Comment: look for "eager loading"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the information from the database:

```
@filings = Filing.includes(:company).order("created_at DESC").offset(start).limit(limit)
```

*hat tip to John Naegle and tharrison*