# Rails query for models having has_many and belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am fairly new to rails. I have the following models

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :options
  has_many :response_parts
end

class ResponsePart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

The corresponding scaffolds are

```
rails g scaffold Question qorder:string qtext:text qtype:string

rails g scaffold ResponsePart answer:string question:belongs_to
```

Now I want all the response parts where qtype is 'mobile'. I have tried a few ways but could not query successfully. Can someone tell a way to make such query. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the relation between the two model and add a constraint on it:

```
ResponsePart.includes(:question).where(questions: { qtype: 'mobile' })
```

This will retrieve all the ResponsePart objects from the DB having a question which match "`qtype == 'mobile'`"

This is also the most efficient way to retrieve these records.

---

```
Question.where(qtype: 'mobile').collect(&:response_parts)
```

This will query the DB to get the corresponding response_parts of each question having "`qtype == 'mobile'`" 
*Example:* If you have 6 questions with "`qtype == 'mobile'`", it will create 6 SQL queries for each Question.

```
Question.where(qtype: "mobile").first.response_parts
```

This just retrieves the ResponsePart objects related to the first question matching the condition "`qtype == 'mobile'`"

Comment: Thanks. I get ` #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<ResponsePart id: 27, answer: "8953453689", question_id: 7, response_id: 8>, #<ResponsePart id: 31, answer: "123456", question_id: 7, response_id: 9>]>` when I query `ResponsePart.includes(:question).where(questions: { qtype: 'mobile' })`. But now I want to access the corresponding answer values. When I use 'ResponsePart.includes(:question).where(questions: { qtype: 'mobile' }).each and try to access the values using .answer it gives an error undefined method `answer`. Am I accessing the values incorrectly?

Comment: Hmm that would concern another question, but we can answer it here. Make sure you are using the right variable: in your view, you should have something like `ResponsePart.includes(:question).where(questions: { qtype: 'mobile' }).each do |response_part|` then you should be able to access the answer value by doing `response_part.answer` in the block of the .each iterator --- If you don't understand this, I need to know what you're using in your views: HAML or ERB? Then I'll show you an example

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Question.where(qtype: 'mobile').collect(&:response_parts)
```

This will give you all the `response_parts` for all the `questions` with `qtype = 'mobile'`

**Update: (Avoiding N+1 queries)**

```
Question.where(qtype: 'mobile').collect(&:response_parts)
```

This will execute a select query on each `response_parts` for each `question` leading to the "N+1" queries.

In order to avoid "N+1 queries" i.e. one Query to retrieve question and `n` queries to retrieve `resposne_parts`, you can add `includes(:join_relation)` (where `:join_relation` is `response_parts` in your case) as follows:

```
Question.includes(:response_parts).where(qtype: 'mobile').collect(&:response_parts)
```

Comment: This is not optimized, if there is X Question where `qtype == 'mobile'`, it will generate X SQL queries to retrieve them. (The famous N+1 Queries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452340/preventing-n1-queries-in-rails)

Comment: Thanks @MrYoshiji, I've updated my answer to address the "N+1" queries issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Question.where(qtype: "mobile").first.response_parts
```

Comment: This does not fill the requirements: It gets only the response_parts of the first question, not all of the questions.

Comment: @MrYoshiji ohh i see . yes you are correct i misinterpret the question . Good Catch